# "Взаправдашный" — есть ли такое слово?

Tags: лексика

Иногда встречается такое слово, но насколько оно литературное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словари дают два варианта: ВЗАПРАВДАШН**ИЙ**, -яя, -ее и ВЗАПРАВДАШН**ЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. Значение - *настоящий, подлинный*. Эти слова к литературным не относятся, а к разговорным.

Comment: Всегда знал, что разговорная лексика относится к литературному языку, а просторечная не входит в лит. язык. Разве что-то изменилось?